# Using a Details View, is there any way during Page_Load (or anywhere) to only display non-null fields?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've been receiving help with a program I've been working on from you guys (and I really appreciate it as I'm fairly new to `ASP.NET`), but now I'm stuck again.
I've got my `List<Products>` that contains one Product object with 17 properties(representing the fields).  Some of these properties may be null(well actually, I already coded it so that if the field in the database was null, convert the properties to either "" or -1).

Is there any way to only create fields for the properties that aren't `null` in my Details View using `ASP.NET/C#` or do I have to use `Javascript` or something else?  I can provide what I have thus far if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your product class make all properties Nullable

like `int? productId`

so it will not bind when it's value is null

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: You mean it will automatically not bind when it's null or do I have to check if it's null and then tell it not to bind?